# How to determine HOW a form field value has changed, not just that it has?

Tags: javascript, debugging, events

I maintain an organizational website that includes a number of forms generated by a third-party CRM. These forms pull in JavaScript, for submission validation and more, from the CRM, but there's also some JavaScript code involved that I own on my side.

A few weeks ago, my organization began getting end-user complaints about people being unable to successfully submit these forms. I've been unable to reproduce the problem. What I have done is add and iterate persistent logging of client-side interaction with these forms, in hopes of being able to drill down on the root cause, whether it is a validation bug or unanticipated user behavior.

In these logs I am seeing that users are submitting forms with invalid values for one particular, conditionally-displayed text input. The invalid input value is always the same across users, and based on the change/input events I've added to both fields, it appears that something somewhere is automatically and erroneously populating the conditionally-displayed field with a bad value, with no indication in my logs that the user has interacted with the parent field at all. This shouldn't be possible in our UI, so you can see why I'm considering all the JavaScript on these pages as my number one suspect here.

I'm hitting a wall, because I cannot modify the CRM's JavaScript to include any logging or dumping (though I can put my own scripting on the overall page via page wrappers etc); I cannot read their code very well because it's been aggressively minified/uglified; and past experience suggests that the CRM's support staff will be unwilling to get involved until/unless I can say that code on their side is absolutely the problem, with steps to reproduce and all.

This feels a bit like asking for a magic spell, but is there any way I can get closer to figuring out the origin of the field value change? Open to using jQuery or other libraries or really anything. This problem is hitting our bottom line, and I am pretty stuck.

Comment: If you are getting an event from the input, it's most likely not a script. You can check the stack trace for synthetic events though. If something is filling out hidden input forms, it's more likely to be a browser extension.

Comment: I found the root cause of my specific problem—seems like Firefox 81 had a change to its form field autofill that now will use the saved "country or region" value to populate any field with country anywhere in the field name. My conditionally displayed field is named "custom_country_field_1" but a country code like "US" (which is the bad input I saw over and over again in my logs) is invalid for what the field actually is. Incredibly annoying, but at least it's an answer. It's not an answer to the question as I asked it here, though, so... not sure what to do with this question 

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array or object out of your data by using the spread operator. And then, check the fields one by one.

```
<input type="text" name="name" onkeyup="setValue('name')" />
<input type="text" name="email" onkeyup="setValue('email')" />
```

```
// let say your data:
let data = {
  name: "something",
  email: "some@thing.com",
}

let unmutatedData = {...data}; // If data is an array use [...data]

function checkForMutations(field) {
   if (data[field] !== unmutatedData[field]) {
    console.log(`${field} has changed`)
  }
}

function setValue(field) {
  data[field] = event.target.value;
  checkForMutations(field);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, but my input and change events are already telling me if something has changed. What I'm after is to find out how and why; what was the trigger? Was it changed by direct user input or by a script or something else? Even, in my fantasy world, what script and what line—but in this world, I'd settle for anything at all in that direction.